# difference between Calibre's metadata.opf and content.opf

Tags: calibre

I created an ebook with Sigil, then I converted it to mobi using Calibre. While I was at it, I edited (Calibre's) metadata and set Italian as language. A friend of mine warned me that hyphenation was English and not Italian: indeed I reopened the file with Sigil and found that in content.opf the language was en, not it.

Is this a known issue / a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calibre's metadata.opf is only used for Calibre purposes. If you change metadata entries with Calibre, the epub isn't immediately updated. IMHO, this is a major bug, but Kovid Goyal apparently considers it a feature.

If you want to apply the changes to the book, you'll have to select **Save to Disk** and save the book to a new folder. 
Alternatively, install the [Modify Epub](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=154371) Calibre plugin and select **Metadata > Update Metadata**.